# How we handle duplicate function names with same parameters in two different files during minification of javascript?

Tags: javascript, webpack, gulp, minify, bundling-and-minification

I want to know how minification libraries like Terser, Uglify handles duplicate function names during minification process?

Comment: Why would you have duplicate function names?

Comment: change the function names?

Comment: Let's suppose ,we have many javascript files, and a function name with same parameters is repeated. How will minification be of these files be done and combined into a single file

Comment: If you don't minify, that code would not work; one of the functions would overwrite the other.

Comment: If you're using a bundler (like webpack) you should be using modules

Comment: I am new to JavaScript, can you please elaborate more or any other useful links where I can read from